# Cannot install WINE on Debian 12

Tags: wine

I'm running Debian 12 (bookworm). I'm trying to install WINE.
I've done the following:

```
curl -fSsL https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg > /dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg] http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https curl -y
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install winehq-stable --install-recommends
```

At this point, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.2~bookworm-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I verified the following:

- `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`
- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq.list`
- `/usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg`

I tried all of the following with no success:

- `sudo apt --fix-missing update`

  - `sudo apt update`
  - `sudo apt install -f`
- `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
- `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
- `dpkg -l | grep ^..r`

As best as I can tell, I have ***no*** broken or held packages whatsoever.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you're using external repos instead of just installing from Debian (older version)?

Comment: The Debian 12 repo is a tad behind. I was looking for the most recent stable version straight from WineHQ. I'm still concerned that the "official" install process as detailed by WineHQ for Debian 12 fails w/o a better explanation than "package X _may_ be interfering." I don't need WINE badly enough to start uninstalling random packages until things work. I'll either use the slightly older package form the Debian repo (and its install process) or just forego WINE altogether.

Comment: The "tad behind" version in the Debian repo install perfectly and doesr 99.999% of what the current version at WineHQ. Someone who doesn't *need WINE badly enough* the smart option is obvious.

Comment: I appreciate the snark. ;) The smart option *is* obvious. Regardless, I've never been a fan of 3rd-party repos anyway.